# how to split string and add additional strin to it

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a string and i need to add some html tag at certain index of the string.

```
$comment_text = 'neethu and Dilnaz Patel  check this'
Array ( [start_index_key] => 0 [string_length] => 6 )
Array ( [start_index_key] => 11 [string_length] => 12 )
```

i need to split at start index key with long mentioned in string_length

expected final output is

```
$formattedText = '<span>@neethu</span> and <span>@Dilnaz Patel</span>  check this'
```

what should i do?

Comment: create array from space and use 0 th and last position for start and edning.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra am sorry but i dnt get ur point

Comment: where is *neethu*, or *Dilnaz Patel* coming from? form input of a name field? data base query result? or someone typed it in a form at a whole? If the latter, what do you expect to happen if someone writes *annnd* or any other typos?

Comment: these name coming from backend side. i changed my code as  @Gil said, while saving i added span and class using jquery then i saved as jsonencode now its working fine ..

Answer (score 1):

This is a very strict method that will break at the first change.
Do you have control over the creation of the string? If so, you can create a string with placeholders and fill the values.

Even though you can do this with regex:

```
$pattern = '/(.+[^ ])\s+and (.+[^ ])\s+check this/i';
$string = 'neehu and Dilnaz Patel  check this';
$replace = preg_replace($pattern, '<b>@$\1</b> and <b>@$\2</b>  check this', $string);
```

But this is still a very rigid solution.

If you can try creating a string with placeholders for the names. this will be much easier to manage and change in the future.

Comment: its a sample text soo the text content will differ

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php



function my_replace($string,$array_break)
{
    $break_open = array();
    $break_close = array();
    
    $start = 0;
    foreach($array_break as $key => $val)
    {
        // for tag <span>
        if($key % 2 == 0)
        {
            $start = $val;
            $break_open[] = $val;
        }
        else
        {
            // for tag </span>
            $break_close[] = $start + $val;
        }
    }
    
    $result = array();
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($string);$i++)
    {
        $current_char = $string[$i];
        
        if(in_array($i,$break_open))
        {
            $result[] = "<span>".$current_char;
        }
        else if(in_array($i,$break_close))
        {
            $result[] = $current_char."</span>";
        }
        else
        {
            $result[] = $current_char;
        }
        
    }
    return implode("",$result);
}

$comment_text = 'neethu and Dilnaz Patel  check this';


$my_result =  my_replace($comment_text,array(0,6,11,12));

var_dump($my_result);
```

Explaination:

Create array parameter with: The even index (0,2,4,6,8,...) would be `start_index_key` and The odd index (1,3,5,7,9,...) would be `string_length`

read every break point , and store it in `$break_open`  and `$break_close`

create array $result for result.

Loop your string, add , add  or dont add spann with break_point

Result:
`string '<span>neethu </span>and <span>Dilnaz Patel </span> check this' (length=61)`